# How to read JFR in JDK 11

Tags: java, profiling, jmc, jfr

I generated a jfr file using Java Flight Recorder and I want to convert that to a flame graph compatible format ( https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph ). Is there any Java classes to read a jfr file. In java 7 we had

```
import com.jrockit.mc.common.IMCFrame;
import com.jrockit.mc.common.IMCMethod;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.FlightRecording;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.FlightRecordingLoader;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.internal.model.FLRStackTrace;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.spi.IEvent;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.spi.IEventType;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.spi.IField;
import com.jrockit.mc.flightrecorder.spi.IView;
```

But I want to to know are there any alternatives in JDK 11, I don't see Java Mission control in /lib/ directory

Comment: we did not have jrockit in Java 7.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-java-flight-recorder-with-openjdk-11-1

Comment: Its in <javahome>/lib/missioncontrol/ directory, we had to manually add that to class path @AlexeiKaigorodov

Answer (score 3):

JDK 11 comes with an API.

The following snippets prints a histogram of the hottest methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     if (args.length != 1) {
         System.err.println("Must specify a recording file.");
         return;
     }

     RecordingFile.readAllEvents(Path.of(args[0])).stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getEventType().getName().equals("jdk.ExecutionSample"))
         .map(e -> e.getStackTrace())
         .filter(s -> s != null)
         .map(s -> s.getFrames().get(0))
         .filter(f -> f.isJavaFrame())
         .map(f -> f.getMethod())
         .collect(
             Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getType().getName() + "." + m.getName() + " " + m.getDescriptor(),
             Collectors.counting()))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()))
         .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%8d %s\n", e.getValue(), e.getKey()));
 }
```

API reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/package-summary.html

"Flight Recorder API Programmer’s Guide":

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jfapi/

Comment: I wanted this information so bad, thanks for your fast reply I'll look into it

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you run into issues. This might be useful as well:
https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to generate a flame graph, you can do that for any set of events from within JMC. Simply download the latest 8.0 EA build of JDK Mission Control, for example from:
https://adoptopenjdk.net/jmc

Then go to Window -> Show View -> Mission Control / Flame View.
(Will not work on Windows just yet.)

Now, any thing representing a selection of events will be rendered as a Flame Graph in that view.

You can grab the code to generate the flame graph from https://github.com/openjdk/jmc (check out https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/blob/master/application/org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.flameview/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmc/flightrecorder/flameview/tree/TraceTreeUtils.java for example), though if you wait a week or two, it will be even easier once https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JMC-6787 is checked in.

Comment: I rather looked into a code-level approach but this made my life easier thanks for the fast reply

Comment: We will likely be contributing the code required to generate the various JSon formats for graphs and flame graphs next week. There will be a new bundle in JMC core for those. This should make it easier for you to code your own solutions, should you want to.

Comment: Adding a further note, its really hard to generate the flamegraphs, JMC crashes most of the time in JMC 8.0 EA release, and JMC 7.1.2 takes so long to create flame graphs.

@Hirt that's good news, if there is a way to compare JFRs that would be amazing

Comment: Is Flame View still not working on Windows ?
I downloaded the latest version on Windows 10, and the Flame View tab is just empty when I select a method.

Comment: The Flame View will work on all platforms as soon as https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/pull/408 is in. You can either build your own JMC today with this PR, grab a JMC 9 early access build once the change is in, or wait for JMC 9 to come out (likely by the end of the year, but no promises yet).